# JUnit tests fail with timeout on a Jenkins slave

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration

The are several performance heavy tests in our projects that run successfully on every dev machine but from time to time they fail on the Jenkins slave that runs them. Can server overload cause these failures? If can, the only way to solve this is to reduce the overload?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I  get tons of failure when server gets busy.

You could try with [Build-Timeout](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) plugin with elastic time out option.

> elastic timeout option to define timeout as a percent of previous
>   build duration

Comment: A timeout value is set in our JUnit tests so unfortunately this plugin would not affect the stability of the build process.

Comment: You need to make that value configurable or get faster machine.